# All blog posts are not showing up

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination

This post may already exists but I just missed it in how I searched for it. Here goes. I have recently changed my blog back to the Genesis Framework. I am using the Nameless child theme.

These are my issues:

1. The only way the front page shows up correctly is for me to select
   "Show latest posts" in the Settings---->Reading section
2. Only my posts are showing up and not those of the other authors. I
   created a page called "Blog" and entered the code below, but it
   still only shows my posts.

My template file:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/
get_header();

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'any', #all post types
    'posts_per_page' => 10 #get 10 posts
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($query->have_posts()):
  while($query->have_posts()):
    $query->the_post();
    the_title(); #display the title
  endwhile;
endif;

get_footer();
```

In the author box I see where different authors can be chosen by the post, but I need all posts by all authors showing up in the listing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a link to my site, if that helps: http://fullfigureplus.com

Comment: I'm a bit confused from your description: are you displaying your blog posts index on the **site front page**, or on a **static page**? What are your settings for **Front page displays**, and, if applicable, **Front page** and **Posts page**?

Comment: I guess they would be on a static page, but I am not sure. My settings are Front page displays---->your latest posts.

Comment: If **Front page displays** is set to **your latest posts**, then your blog posts index is being displayed on the site front page. Do all posts show up there?

Comment: No they do not. They show up based on the widget settings for the child theme. I have a link at the top of the page titles "latest blog posts" that is linked to a page I created called "Blog" The problem is it only shows posts from 10 days ago and only shows my posts not the other author.

Comment: Your "blog" template won't factor in here. WordPress simply won't use it to display your blog posts index. WordPress will only use `home.php` or `index.php` (unless on the site front page, in which case WordPress will first try to use `front-page.php`).

Comment: Try switching to a core-bundled Theme, such as Twenty Thirteen or Twenty Twelve. If the front page properly displays your blog posts index, then the issue is specific to Genesis. If that's the case, then the question is **off topic** for WPSE, and you'll need to seek support from StudioPress.

Comment: Your [blog page](http://fullfigureplus.com/blog/) seems to be displaying posts from more than one author. Did you find/fix the problem?

Comment: I was reading the beginners guide to Genesis and it walked me through what to do. It was only displaying the posts from one category. I feel silly missing such an obvious fix. Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix pagination for custom loops?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. The only way the front page shows up correctly is for me to select "Show latest posts" in the Settings---->Reading section

That is the default way most Genesis child themes work and there is nothing in the Nameless theme code that suggests the theme author expected anyone to use a *static* front page. Genesis was not knowingly designed that way, but all pre-Genesis StudioPress themes required the "Show latest post" setting to run properly.

I recall doing a few tests for static pages (Geneis Breadcrumbs comes to mind.) during Genesis testing, but Brian never uses static pages for his child themes. So, expect the same problems all WordPress static pages have (like pagination problems).

> 1. Only my posts are showing up and not those of the other authors. I created a page called "Blog" and entered the code below, but it still only shows my posts.

Genesis already has Blog page template and a looks for a custom field named `query_args` for WP_Query loop settings. There are also settings for the Genesis Theme Settings page. The `query_args` custom field overrides the Theeme Settings page settings.

- Delete the Blog page template file in the child theme.
- Edit your blog page.
- Add a custom field name `query_args`.
- Set the value to `post_type=any`. The number of posts per page are set in the Genesis Theme Settings page.
- Go to the Genesis Theme Setings page (`/wp-admin/admin.php?page=genesis`) and set the Blog Page Template settings.

That will do the same thing as your code and will call all the extra Genesis page stuff as well. Note: `query_args` can only accept WP_Query string parameters. More complicated queries may be added using the `'genesis_custom_loop_args'` filter.

Comment: I was reading the beginners guide to Genesis and it walked me through what to do. It was only displaying the posts from one category. I feel silly missing such an obvious fix. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @GlenJohnson I know this is an old post, but it's coming up in our unanswered list. If you're still around, please use the checkmark to the left of this answer to mark it as answered :) thanks!